# wrapping JSON elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If I do this, i receive all of the proper data in firebug

```
 $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDPuIrijE0IQ6330vMLN2p-L_4J6y_G60c&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=cars&alt=json&callback=?",
               {

               },
               function (recievedData) {
                   console.log(recievedData);
});
```

The data is structured like this(it's really long, so I put it in a fiddle)

http://jsfiddle.net/tsDrv/

if you want to see it in full, put this in your browser:
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDPuIrijE0IQ6330vMLN2p-L_4J6y_G60c&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=cars&alt=json

All I want to do is crack open the "items" and wrap them in

to display on page, so I try this:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDPuIrijE0IQ6330vMLN2p-L_4J6y_G60c&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=cars&alt=json&callback=?",
               {

               },
               function (recievedData) {
                   $.each(recievedData, function (i, item) {
                       $('#theBody').append(
                           $(document.createElement('li')).text(item.items)
                       );
                   });
               });
```

Firebug doesn't read an error, but nothing shows up, I did try it another way and kept getting [object Object] how can I access deep into the JSON array to display this on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code. Currently I have read snippet using `item.snippet`, similarly you can read `item.title`, `item.displayLink`, `item.formattedUrl` etc.

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDPuIrijE0IQ6330vMLN2p-L_4J6y_G60c&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=cars&alt=json&callback=?",
               function (recievedData) {
                //console.log(recievedData);
                   $.each(recievedData.items, function (i, item) {
                       $('#theBody').append(
                           $(document.createElement('li')).text(item.snippet)
                       );
                   });
               });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/evXDJ/)**

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to append li elements, you should wrap it into ul elements.
Since your json has deep structure, you should implement a recursive element builder function which calls itself till a leaf is met.

If your aim is finally to display the JSON content without styling, you should hav a pre element and set its text to `JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject, null, "\t")`.